# node-dev not installing and runs only once

Tags: node.js, node-dev

I am new to nodejs and i am trying to run the following command

```
sudo npm install node-dev -g
```

I get the following message

```
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
/usr/local/bin/node-dev -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/bin/node-dev

node-dev@2.6.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev
├── filewatcher@1.1.2
├── resolve@1.1.6
├── dynamic-dedupe@0.2.0 (xtend@2.0.6)
├── dateformat@1.0.11 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.1.0)
└── node-notifier@4.2.1 (shellwords@0.1.0, clone@0.1.19, growly@1.2.0, minimist@1.1.1, semver@4.3.6, cli-usage@0.1.1, which@1.1.1)
```

And then when i do

```
node-dev demo2.js
```

the javascript file does not run continuously. Can anyone help me with this ? I want to run the file continuously with node-dev

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I used the following instead: npm install nodev@0.8.1

This worked great. See this link for more info: https://libraries.io/npm/nodev/0.8.1